# Css className:nth-child - как сделать подобие nth-child для класса

Tags: css, css-selectors

Есть группа `li` элементов с заданным классам. Как выбрать ряд и отдельные элементы (`input` в `li`) для определенного класса?

```css
.thirdCol input[type='text'] {
  color: green;
}

.thirdCol input[type='text'] {
  border: 1px dotted #8e1;
}

li:nth-child(7) input[type='text'] {
  color: olive;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

// select 2,3,4 of 'thirdCol' class
.thirdCol:nth-child(n+2) input[type='text'] {
  border: 3px dotted #372;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='TTT'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text' value='TTT'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А можете уточнить какое поведение хочется, а какое получается? А то так неясно что именно вам надо.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov
Получается ни какого вообще поведение с данным кодом. Ищу красивый/эффективный способ выбрать, например, все элементы, начиная с 3го для всех элементов с определенным классом.
`.thirdCol:nth-child(n+2)` -- оно могло бы работать для `li`, но для класса `nth-child` не работает. Вот и ищу работающий аналог данного псевдокода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, то что вы просите невозможно средствами CSS в одном красивом селекоторе.
В данном конкретном случае можно попробовать `nth-last-child` (то есть выбрать с конца), но не уверен, что это подойдёт.
Придётся использоваться JavaScript.
Если есть возможность использовать jQuery, то тогда решение для выбора элементов с классом `.thirdCol` начинания с третьего будет выглядеть так:

```js
$(".thirdCol:gt(1) input[type='text']").css("border", "3px dotted #372");
```

```css
.thirdCol input[type='text'] {
  color: green;
}

.thirdCol input[type='text'] {
  border: 1px dotted #8e1;
}

li:nth-child(7) input[type='text'] {
  color: olive;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text'/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='TTT'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text' value='TTT'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
  <li class='thirdCol'><input type='text'/></li>
</ul>
```

В примере используется селектор `:gt` означающий greater than, который принимает номер элемента, после которого (невключительно) применяется селектор; нумерация начинается с нуля. Так как нам нужен элементы начиная с 3 включительно, то передаём 1.

---

### UPD

Так как есть возможность менять только CSS то можно попытаться решить через хак:  можно воспользоваться селектором так называемым general sibling combinator selector (~) и придётся на каждый элемент последовательности его генерировать.

```
.thirdCol ~ .thirdCol ~ .thirdCol input[type='text'], /* Выбираем третий элемент  .thirdCol */
.thirdCol ~ .thirdCol ~ .thirdCol ~ .thirdCol input[type='text'], /* Выбираем четвёртый элемент  .thirdCol */
… и т.д. {
  border: 3px dotted #372;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! но я должен только css (Stylus) использовать. Но да, похоже, только c css проблему не решить.

Comment: Хорошо, смотрите update.